# Map a Future for both Success and Failure

Tags: scala, future

I have a Future[T] and I want to map the result, on both success and failure.

Eg, something like

```
val future = ... // Future[T]
val mapped = future.mapAll { 
  case Success(a) => "OK"
  case Failure(e) => "KO"
}
```

If I use `map` or `flatmap`, it will only map successes futures. If I use `recover`, it will only map failed futures. `onComplete` executes a callback but does not return a modified future. `Transform` will work, but takes 2 functions rather than a partial function, so is a bit uglier.

I know I could make a new `Promise`, and complete that with `onComplete` or `onSuccess`/`onFailure`, but I was hoping there was something I was missing that would allow me to do the above with a single PF.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Edit 2017-09-18: As of Scala 2.12, there is a `transform` method that takes a `Try[T] => Try[S]`. So you can write

```
val future = ... // Future[T]
val mapped = future.transform {
  case Success(_) => Success("OK")
  case Failure(_) => Success("KO")
}
```

For 2.11.x, the below still applies:

AFAIK, you can't do this directly with a single PF.  And `transform` transforms Throwable => Throwable, so that won't help you either. The closest you can get out of the box:

```
val mapped: Future[String] = future.map(_ => "OK").recover{case _ => "KO"}
```

That said, implementing your mapAll is trivial:

```
implicit class RichFuture[T](f: Future[T]) {
  def mapAll[U](pf: PartialFunction[Try[T], U]): Future[U] = {
    val p = Promise[U]()
    f.onComplete(r => p.complete(Try(pf(r))))
    p.future
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I could easily write it, just wondered if something like that was lurking about somewhere.

Comment: Hi @espenhw, in the 2nd paragraph in your answer, did you actually  mean
`val mapped: Future[String] = future.map(_ => "OK").recover{case _ => "KO")`

Comment: It was driving me crazy not figuring out which combinator to use - especially since .onComplete has exactly the signature I want, except it doesn't give me a new future. I'll use this solution; thanks.

Comment: the thing is the .map could fail and you'd recover it erroneously (in the sense we only wanted to recover from things in the initial future).

Comment: Can we update this answer with the new `transform` method introduced as part of Scala 2.12?

Answer (score 7):

Since [Scala 2.12](https://nmatpt.com/blog/2017/02/09/scala-2.12-future-transform/) you can use `transform` to map both cases:

```
future.transform {
      case Success(_) => Try("OK")
      case Failure(_) => Try("KO")
}
```

You also have `transformWith` if you prefer to use a `Future` instead of a `Try`. Check the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/concurrent/Future.html) for details.

Answer (score 4):

In a first step, you could do something like:

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

val g = future.map( Success(_):Try[T] ).recover{
  case t => Failure(t)
}.map {
  case Success(s) => ...
  case Failure(t) => ...
}
```

where `T` is the type of the future result. Then you can use an implicit conversion to add this structure the `Future` trait as a new method:

```
implicit class MyRichFuture[T]( fut: Future[T] ) {
  def mapAll[U]( f: PartialFunction[Try[T],U] )( implicit ec: ExecutionContext ): Future[U] = 
    fut.map( Success(_):Try[T] ).recover{
      case t => Failure(t)
    }.map( f )
 }
```

which implements the syntax your are looking for:

```
val future = Future{ 2 / 0 }
future.mapAll {
  case Success(i) => i + 0.5
  case Failure(_) => 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both map and flatMap variants:

```
implicit class FutureExtensions[T](f: Future[T]) {
  def mapAll[Target](m: Try[T] => Target)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Target] = {
    val promise = Promise[Target]()
    f.onComplete { r => promise success m(r) }(ec)
    promise.future
  }

  def flatMapAll[Target](m: Try[T] => Future[Target])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Target] = {
    val promise = Promise[Target]()
    f.onComplete { r => m(r).onComplete { z => promise complete z }(ec) }(ec)
    promise.future
  }
}
```